# Unnecessary rerenders using Apollo + useContext for Authentication (SSR)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, apollo

I'm experiencing rerenders *seemingly* as a result of `useQuery` being called when I don't want it to be.

First load, `isAuthenticated`'s state is instantiated via a function that makes a query to the server to get the userId based on the attached header.
If a valid header is present, `isAuthenticated` is set to true and therefore `useMemo` is called (as `isAuthenticated` is a dependency). `useMemo` calls `setUser`, which puts the userId and role into the context, to be passed down through the AuthProvider (in `_app`, wrapping everything but the ApolloProvider).

I use the userId in the Navbar (via `useContext`) to get the avatar (and other things in the rest of the app). What I've noticed is that any time I click on something (for example, a separate query filtering products), the `CURRENT_USER` query in `_app` is called. And this manifests as the Navbar losing the useId data passed to it for a second, and then reverts back. So, everytime I click on things, my Navbar is rerendering. I don't understand why the `CURRENT_USER` query keeps being called...

For context, I use the same setup in another app that does not have SSR without issue.

`auth.context.js`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo} from "react";
import { CURRENT_USER } from "graphql/query/customer.query";
import { gql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import { isBrowser } from "components/helpers/isBrowser";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(CURRENT_USER, {
    onCompleted: () => {
      console.log("called query", data);
    },
    ssr: true,
  });
  const isValidToken = () => {
    if (isBrowser) {
      const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      if (error) {
        return false;
      }
      if (!loading && !data) {
        return false;
      }
      if (token && data?.currentUser) {
        console.log(data.currentUser);
        return true;
      }
      if (!token) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  };
  const [isAuthenticated, makeAuthenticated] = useState(isValidToken());
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  function authenticate() {
    console.log(isAuthenticated);
    makeAuthenticated(isValidToken());
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("attempted to run");
    if (data && isAuthenticated) {
      setUser(data.currentUser);
      console.log("user", user);
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated]);
  function signout() {
    makeAuthenticated(false);
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
  }
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        isAuthenticated,
        authenticate,
        signout,
        user,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

"@apollo/client": "^3.0.0-beta.44",

"next": "^9.3.6",

"react": "^16.13.1",

Comment: plz, could u show me more code of your Navbar and a component where u click causing re-render NavBar?

Comment: Ok so when I click on links that change the route (but don't cause the page to rerender), which are used for triggering a different query (filtering products), this causes the rerender. I'll update code above.

Comment: @Michael having issues updating this question for some reason, [so I made a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61895397/apollo-queries-triggered-and-causing-rerendering-in-usecontext-on-url-change). I added a gif showing the rerender and state change, as well as the Header code you asked for!